# VBA stepping through code works, button does not

Tags: vba, excel, formatting

I am able to step through the macro but the button does not function correctly. 
What I'm trying to do is just format the sheet to arrange the columns in this specific order:

```
vCOLs = Array("Purchase Order", "Document Number", "Invoice Date", _
"Invoice Number", "Business Unit", "Object", "Subsidiary", "G/L Date", _
"Period Number", "Fiscal Year", "Supplier", "Name", _
"Supplier Name/ Explanation", "Description", "Explanation -Remark-", _
"Amount")
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Dim a As Long, w As Long, x As Long, col As Long, lRow As Long
Dim c As Long, vCOLs As Variant
Dim vDELCOLs As Variant, vCOLNDX As Variant, N As Variant
Dim sht As Range, ACell As Range, Rng As Range
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb1 = Workbooks("Sourcing KPI Spend Report Q3 2017.xlsm")
Set sht = wb1.Sheets("Spend Report").UsedRange
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Spend Report")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ws.Rows("1:6").Delete
sht.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="

sht.Offset(1, 0).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete (xlShiftUp)
sht.AutoFilter
sht.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="="
sht.Offset(1, 0).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete (xlShiftUp)
sht.AutoFilter

vDELCOLs = Array("Account Number", "Batch Type", "Batch Number", "Doc Type", _
   "Company", "LT", "Transaction Currency", "Base Currency", "Work Order", _
      "Subledger", "Subledger Type", "Transaction Originator")

With Sheets("Spend Report")
    For a = LBound(vDELCOLs) To UBound(vDELCOLs)
        vCOLNDX = Application.Match(vDELCOLs(a), .Rows(1), 0)
            If Not IsError(vCOLNDX) Then
                .Columns(vCOLNDX).EntireColumn.Delete
            End If
    Next a
End With

ColCount = Sheets("Spend Report").Cells(1, 
Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

sht.EntireColumn.Insert (ColCount)
```

This is where it starts to break

```
For i = 35 To 1 Step -1
    If ws.Cells(1, i) = "Purchase Order" Then
        ws.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Cut
        Range("A1").Activate
        ws.Paste
    End If
Next

For i = 35 To 1 Step -1
    If ws.Cells(1, i) = "Document Number" Then
        ws.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Cut
        Range("B1").Activate
        ws.Paste
    End If
Next

For i = 35 To 1 Step -1
    If ws.Cells(1, i) = "Invoice Date" Then
        ws.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Cut
        Range("C1").Activate
        ws.Paste
    End If
Next

For i = 35 To 1 Step -1
    If ws.Cells(1, i) = "Invoice Number" Then
        ws.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Cut
        Range("D1").Activate
        ws.Paste
    End If
Next

For i = 35 To 1 Step -1
    If ws.Cells(1, i) = "Business Unit" Then
        ws.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Cut
        Range("E1").Activate
        ws.Paste
    End If
Next

For i = 35 To 1 Step -1
    If ws.Cells(1, i) = "Object" Then
        ws.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Cut
        Range("F1").Activate
        ws.Paste
    End If
Next

For i = 35 To 1 Step -1
    If ws.Cells(1, i) = "Subsidiary" Then
        ws.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Cut
        Range("G1").Activate
        ws.Paste
    End If
Next


For i = 35 To 1 Step -1
    If ws.Cells(1, i) = "G/L Date" Then
        ws.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Cut
        Range("H1").Activate
        ws.Paste
    End If
Next

For i = 35 To 1 Step -1
    If ws.Cells(1, i) = "Period Number" Then
        ws.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Cut
        Range("I1").Activate
        ws.Paste
    End If
Next

For i = 35 To 1 Step -1
    If ws.Cells(1, i) = "Fiscal Year" Then
        ws.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Cut
        Range("J1").Activate
        ws.Paste
    End If
Next

For i = 35 To 1 Step -1
    If ws.Cells(1, i) = "Supplier" Then
        ws.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Cut
        Range("K1").Activate
        ws.Paste
    End If
Next

For i = 35 To 1 Step -1
    If ws.Cells(1, i) = "Name" Then
        ws.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Cut
        Range("L1").Activate
        ws.Paste
    End If
Next

For i = 35 To 1 Step -1
    If ws.Cells(1, i) = "Supplier Name/ Explanation" Then
        ws.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Cut
        Range("M1").Activate
        ws.Paste
    End If
Next

For i = 35 To 1 Step -1
    If ws.Cells(1, i) = "Description" Then
        ws.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Cut
        Range("N1").Activate
        ws.Paste
    End If
Next

For i = 35 To 1 Step -1
    If ws.Cells(1, i) = "Explanation -Remark-" Then
        ws.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Cut
        Range("O1").Activate
        ws.Paste
    End If
Next

For i = 35 To 1 Step -1
    If ws.Cells(1, i) = "Amount" Then
        ws.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Cut
        Range("P1").Activate
        ws.Paste
    End If
Next

Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

For i = 17 To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(1, i) = "Purchase Order" Then
        Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If
Next

For i = 17 To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(1, i) = "Document Number" Then
        Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If
Next

For i = 17 To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(1, i) = "Invoice Date" Then
        Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If
Next

For i = 17 To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(1, i) = "Invoice Number" Then
        Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If
Next

'    vCOLs = Array("Purchase Order", "Document Number", "Invoice Date", _
"Invoice Number", "Business Unit", "Object", "Subsidiary", "G/L Date", _
"Period Number", "Fiscal Year", "Supplier", "Name", _
"Supplier Name/ Explanation", "Description", "Explanation -Remark-", _
"Amount")

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Just looking at your loops and not being an expert in VBA I had two questions. 1) when you `range("E1").activate` how does it know which sheet E1 is on?  I would assume it would try to do it on the last "ACTIVE" sheet you had up before running it.  Not sure if this is a different sheet from where the button is and when you step through it. 2)  rather than multiple 35 to 1 loops for i, why not use one loop and just have what you do for individual case under that one loop?

Comment: @Forward Ed - I've tried to identify the worksheets with: Worksheets("Spend Report")..Range("A1").Activate also tried: ws.Range("A1").Activate neither of these worked. However when I removed the worksheet and stepped through. It pasted where the range specifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim DestWS As Worksheet
    Dim DestCell As Range
    Dim FoundHeader As Range
    Dim ColHeaders As Variant
    Dim ColHeader As Variant

    Const HeaderRow = 1     'Note this is the header row after the first 6 rows are deleted
    Const SheetName As String = "Spend Report"

    'Typically you want macros run on the active workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    'If this macro is not being run on the active workbook, you can specify the workbook to run it on
    'To do so, uncomment the below line and comment out the ActiveWorkbook line above
    'Set wb = Workbooks("Sourcing KPI Spend Report Q3 2017.xlsm")

    Set Source = wb.Sheets(SheetName)
    ColHeaders = Array("Purchase Order", "Document Number", "Invoice Date", _
                       "Invoice Number", "Business Unit", "Object", "Subsidiary", "G/L Date", _
                       "Period Number", "Fiscal Year", "Supplier", "Name", _
                       "Supplier Name/ Explanation", "Description", "Explanation -Remark-", _
                       "Amount")

    'Delete first 6 rows
    Source.Range("1:6").EntireRow.Delete

    'Delete rows where there are blank cells in column A or B
    Source.UsedRange.AutoFilter 1, "="
    Source.UsedRange.Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
    Source.UsedRange.AutoFilter
    Source.UsedRange.AutoFilter 2, "="
    Source.UsedRange.Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
    Source.UsedRange.AutoFilter

    'Create new worksheet that will contain the columns in desired order
    Set DestWS = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=Source)
    Set DestCell = DestWS.Range("A1")

    'Cut/paste the columns in the proper order to the new sheet
    For Each ColHeader In ColHeaders
        Set FoundHeader = Source.Rows(HeaderRow).Find(ColHeader, Source.Cells(HeaderRow, Source.Columns.Count), xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not FoundHeader Is Nothing Then
            FoundHeader.EntireColumn.Cut DestCell
            Set DestCell = DestWS.Cells(1, DestWS.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1)
        End If
    Next ColHeader

    'Delete the original which will no longer be used
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Source.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Rename the destination sheet to the proper sheet name
    DestWS.Name = SheetName

End Sub
```

Comment: tigeravatar - You are good sir. You code is so much better and neater than mine. Thank you, I really appreciate it.